# Вопрос по архитектуре приложения yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Я делаю приложение на yii2, называется загрузчик отчетов.
В данный момент он загружает файлы csv и просто их отображает.

Логика такая:

1. Человек заходит на страницу загрузки.
2. Вводит имя таблицы, описание и подписывает номера колонок и имена их.
3. Загружает файл и сабмитит форму.

Я создал три таблицы:

```
id  int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT      
tableName  varchar(255) 
tableDescription  varchar(1024) 
date datetime


id  int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT  
tableId int(11)         
columnName  varchar(1024)   
columnNumber    int(11) 

id  int(11)  AUTO_INCREMENT 
columnId  int(11)           
tableId  int(11)    
value  text 
file  text  
numberRow  int(11)
```

Код действия контролера имеет вид:

```
/**
 * //код действия
 */
public function actionDownload()
{

    $tableId = null;
    $tableModel = new Tables();
    $tableColumns = new TablesColumns();
    $columnsValue = new ColumnsValue();
    if ($argumentsArray = Yii::$app->request->post()) {
        //save data about tables
        if ($tableModel->load($argumentsArray, 'Tables') && $tableModel->validate()) {
            $tableModel->save();
            $tableId = $tableModel->id;
            if (!$tableColumns->saveData($argumentsArray['TablesColumns'], $tableId)) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('errorColumns', "Ошибка при загрузке имен колонок");
            }
            if (!$columnsValue->downloadFile($_FILES['ColumnsValue'], $tableId)) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('errorFile', "Ошибка при загрузке файла");

            }
        }
    }
    return $this->render('download', [
        'tableModel' => $tableModel
    ]);
}
```

Мне, собственно, не нравится идея создания 3-x моделей унаследованных от ActiveRecord. Хотелось бы как-то компактнее все сделать, чтобы можно было масштабировать код без боли)

В дальнейшем я хочу добавить выгрузку из xls

Comment: Вам бы нужно свести построение table к какому-то шаблону проектирования.... пока еще не знаю какому точно.. вам бы почитать о них... Может быть `facade`, где все обращение будет к `table` а он будет рулить своими потомками.. тогда `TablesColumns` и `ColumnsValue` будут просто классами.. не моделями.
...а может паттерн `buider` подойдет........ тогда в `actionDownload` вы будете манипулировать лишь `new Tables()`.... либо кем-то, кто создаст table с его зависимостями

Comment: А вы планируете как-то использовать отдельные значения полей _сами по себе_? Или только в контексте строки таблицы? Планируется ли использовать сортировку/фильтрацию по значениям полей?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev
да, планирую

Comment: просто не удобно, что форма одна, а моделей 3
получается, что валидация работает только для Tables

Comment: @gudfar, количество моделей, если они грамотно представляют сущности реального мира, не имеет значения. Другое дело, что я совсем не представляю, как можно реализовать сортировку при вашей структуре таблиц. Разве что выгружать все данные и сортировать/фильтровать в коде приложения.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev
$tablesColumns = TablesColumns::find()
            ->asArray()
            ->where(['tableid' => $tableId])
            ->orderBy(['columnNumber' => SORT_ASC])
            ->all();

вот допустим вытягиваю данные из таблицы,
собственно а при чем здесь сортировка и т.п.

Comment: Так я о сортировке _строк_ таблицы по _значениям_ полей говорил. Суть в том, что в большинстве случаев, сами по себе значения полей имеют маленькую ценность. Их имеет смысл рассматривать, как целостную _строку данных_.

Comment: еще проблема в том,
что если во второй модели выскочит ошибка,
то нужно дропать таблицу Tables, которая в первой модели.
А это не очень удобно

Answer (score 1):

Я бы раскинул логику контроллера на компоненты и обращался непосредственно к ним

Comment: Старайтесь писать более детальные ответы. Можно включить пример кода, объяснить путь решения, привести ссылки с более подробным разбором проблемы и т. п.